# Double Entries/ Errors with Digitizing Polygons

Tags: polygon, editing, fields-attributes, topology, arcgis-editor-osm

I have a layer that has errors, i mean polygons have double entries (digitized twice), i can edit manually but there's a lot of attributes and it will take ages to clean the data. Is there any short cut key or tool that i can use to pick up these polygons.

Comment: You could build a topology on a copy of the data to see duplicates (must not overlap)... that will help you find them but not for fixing.. is there some sort of rule that would help decide which one stays and which one goes?

Comment: Hi Michael,one can be removed while the other one stays. Its not all the poylgons, just some..Lets say ,more than 1000 attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tools [Find Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000054000000) and [Delete Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000053000000) should be able to assist. The tools find identical data based on the shape or attribute. The down side is that you need ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced to use the tools